# Undefined variable in Option Value CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

What I'm I doing wrong?

**application/views/pegawai_read.php**

```
<select name="" id="" class="form-control">                                        
    <?php
        foreach($nm_berkas_jn->result() as $j){                                     
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $j->id_berkas_jn;?>"><?php echo $j->nm_berkas_jn;?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

**application/controllers/pegawai.php**

```
public function read($id) {
    $id_berkas_jn=$this->session->userdata('id_berkas_jn');
    $text = "SELECT * FROM kpg_berkas_jn";
    $d['nm_berkas_jn'] = $this->app_model->manualQuery($text);
    $d['level']=$this->session->userdata('level');
}
```

**application/models/app_model.php**

```
function manualQuery($q) {
    return $this->db->query($q);
}
```

Comment: What are the variable names (table column names) and its values being returned by the query in model?, also why you are not calling view after calling model method in Controller section?

Comment: The field with **id_berkas_jn** name is exist in database table? Variables in php are case-sensitive! If in the field name is e.g.: **Id_berkas_jn** it is not match with `$j->id_berkas_jn`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the bottom of your controller. This send the data to the view

```
$this->load->view('pegawai_read', $d);
```